# Gerrit configuration with Git

Tags: git, gerrit

I am setting up Gerrit for code review and have a question (which looks like obvious for me) that I didn't find an answer for.

How Can I connect my Gerrit git repo to an existing Git repo that I want to apply code review for?
Either I am misunderstanding the concept or I am missing something.

Any ideas please.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to connect gerrit with github (https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-gerrit-github)

You can basically put any gerrit instance in front of another git system or can use gerrit as your only git repository.

At my company we have gerrit in front of gitlab and it works fine. It has some some caveats since the synchronization plugin can not do pulls but only pushs, so you have to be careful that noone pushs to gitlab. The main two are: only repository owner allowed who can not block himself and admins and project owners can push to master on the gerrit instance (default git push branch).

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit is designed to be the only instance that writes to the main repository.

More repositories on external servers can be kept up to date through the replication plugin (shipped with Gerrit).

The github plugin mentioned by [volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4084601/volker) can AFAIK fetch pull requests into new Gerrit changes for review.